# How to use a conditional aggregate for total gross

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have this query:

```
SELECT CAST(co.DateCreated AS DATE) AS Date, 
SUM(w.Gross),
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.BookingSourceId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Website,
       SUM(CASE WHEN co.BookingSourceId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as Phone,
       COUNT(*) as Total_Orders
FROM [Sterlingbuild].[dbo].[CustomerOrder] co
INNER JOIN ( SELECT Gross, CustomerOrderId, p.ProductBrandId
             FROM [Sterlingbuild].[dbo].[CustomerOrderItem] coi 
             INNER JOIN [Sterlingbuild].[dbo].[Product] p ON coi.ProductId = p.ProductId
             ) w ON co.CustomerOrderId = w.CustomerOrderId
WHERE CustomerOrderStatusId = 7 AND DepartmentId = 1 AND w.ProductBrandId = 7
GROUP BY CAST(co.DateCreated AS DATE)
ORDER BY CAST(co.DateCreated AS DATE)
```

At the moment it returns the number of orders made by phone/website however I want the total GROSS for both phone/website how do I amend the query to achieve this.

Using SQL server

Answer (score 0):

Sum the `gross`:

```
   SUM(CASE WHEN co.BookingSourceId = 1 THEN w.gross ELSE 0 END) as Website_gross,
   SUM(CASE WHEN co.BookingSourceId = 2 THEN w.gross ELSE 0 END) as Phone_gross,
```